# BATCH Variable replace fails

Tags: batch-file

My batch code (Specifically designed to simply change the color) fails because the replace code fails. The text it is supposed to replace comes out like it entered.

```
echo Colors:
echo Black, blue, green, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light blue, light   green, light aqua, light red, light purple, light yellow, and bright white.
set /p COLOR=What color for the background? 
set DASH=%COLOR: =-%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:black=0%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:blue=1%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:green=2%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:aqua=3%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:red=4%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:purple=5%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:yellow=6%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:white=7%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:gray=8%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:grey=8%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-blue=9%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-green=A%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-aqua=B%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-red=C%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-purple=D%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-yellow=E%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:bright-white=F%
cls
echo Colors:
echo Black, blue, green, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light blue, light   green, light aqua, light red, light purple, light yellow, and bright white.
set /p COLOR=What color for the text? 
set DASH=%COLOR: =-%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:black=0%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:blue=1%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:green=2%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:aqua=3%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:red=4%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:purple=5%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:yellow=6%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:white=7%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:gray=8%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:grey=8%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:light-blue=9%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-green=A%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:light-aqua=B%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:light-red=C%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:light-purple=D%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:light-yellow=E%
set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:bright-white=F%
color %COLORSETBACK%%COLORSETTEXT%
```

The set DASH=%COLOR: =-% is to change "light red" to light-red" and it works.
However when I get to the set COLORSETTEXT=%DASH:black=0% the code fails to replace black with 0. I have tried different questions on different parts of the internet with no luck. If I were to type in red for the background and black for the text, the output would be "redblack" and I need it to be "40"

Comment: I see what I did wrong - if I used the same variable, it might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code - does it do what you need?

By uncommenting the two REM statements, they can show you how the text is modified.

```
@echo off
set "foreground="
set "background="

cls
echo Color choices:
echo Black, blue, green, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light blue, light   green, light aqua, light red, light purple, light yellow, and bright white.
echo(
:loop
if not defined foreground set type=text
if not defined background set type=background
set "color="
set /p "COLOR=What color for the %type%? : "
set COLOR=%COLOR: =-%
rem echo %color%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-blue=9%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-green=A%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-aqua=B%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-red=C%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-purple=D%
set COLOR=%COLOR:light-yellow=E%
set COLOR=%COLOR:bright-white=F%
set COLOR=%COLOR:black=0%
set COLOR=%COLOR:blue=1%
set COLOR=%COLOR:green=2%
set COLOR=%COLOR:aqua=3%
set COLOR=%COLOR:red=4%
set COLOR=%COLOR:purple=5%
set COLOR=%COLOR:yellow=6%
set COLOR=%COLOR:white=7%
set COLOR=%COLOR:gray=8%
set COLOR=%COLOR:grey=8%
rem echo %color%
if not defined background set background=%color%&goto :loop
if not defined foreground set foreground=%color%
echo(
echo color %background%%foreground%
pause
```

Comment: This code works fine. It seems like this is exactly what I had written in a different fashion, but it doesn't matter as long as it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your code execute *all lines* each time that a color is read. For example, if the given color is `black`, the *first line* correctly change "black" by "0", but after it the rest of lines are executed, so the *last line* execute `set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:bright-white=F%` and the *original value* of DASH is *not* changed (because it does *not* contain "bright-white"), so `black` is finally assigned again. This means that your code only works when the color read is the last one: "bright-white".

Your code *should have* and `if` command for *each value*, so the rest of replacements be omitted when the right replacement is done. However, this produce very long and ugly code...

The correct way to "process a series of values in the same way" is via a `for` command that vary the value of a *subscript* in combination with the [array concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the "color" array used in the replacement:
set hex=0123456789ABCDEF
set i=0
for %%a in (Black, blue, green, aqua, red, purple, yellow, white, gray,
            light-blue, light-green, light-aqua, light-red, light-purple, light-yellow, bright-white) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do set "color[%%a]=!hex:~%%i,1!"
   set /A i+=1
)

echo Colors:
echo Black, blue, green, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light blue, light green, light aqua, light red, light purple, light yellow, and bright white.
set /p COLOR=What color for the background? 
set DASH=%COLOR: =-%
set COLORSETBACK=!color[%DASH%]!

cls
echo Colors:
echo Black, blue, green, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light blue, light green, light aqua, light red, light purple, light yellow, and bright white.
set /p COLOR=What color for the text? 
set DASH=%COLOR: =-%
set COLORSETTEXT=!color[%DASH%]!

color %COLORSETBACK%%COLORSETTEXT%
```

You may read a further description of array management in Batch files at [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

PS - You have also a couple errors in these lines placed in the *TEXT* section:

```
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:white=7%
set COLORSETBACK=%DASH:light-green=A%
```

**EDIT**: I added the "aqua" color that was missing in the original code. I also made good use of this edit in order to add a smaller solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the "color" array used in the replacement:
set "colors=Black, blue, green, aqua, red, purple, yellow, white, gray, light-blue, light-green, light-aqua, light-red, light-purple, light-yellow, bright-white"
set "hex=0123456789ABCDEF"
set "i=0"
for %%a in (%colors%) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do set "color[%%a]=!hex:~%%i,1!"
   set /A i+=1
)

for %%c in (background text) do (
   cls
   echo Colors:
   echo %colors:-= %
   set /p COLOR=What color for the %%c?
   set "%%c=!color[%COLOR: =-%]!"
)

color %background%%text%
```

Comment: This works... However lots of colors are mixed up. Yellow is purple, bright white is yellow, ect..

Comment: Well, this is because you forgot to include "aqua" color between "green" and "red"! Just insert it in the `for` command...